# complex data restructuring - wide to long (multiple columns)

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

I want to do a restructuring as above, and I'm struggling with just using `gather()` as there are multiple columns to make... does anyone know a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please post your data in copy&paste-able format. No pictures. Meanwhile take a look at `?reshape`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, though prob not the most elegant:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

Example data (based on screen shot):

```
df <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3), 
         mathT1 = c(10, 9, 7),
         mathT2 = c(11, 6, 8),
         write1 = c(2, 3, 1),
         write2 = c(3, 5, 1),
         ses = c(3, 4, 5))
```

code using packages reshape2, dplyr and tidyr:

```
df <- df %>%
  rename(math_1 = mathT1, math_2 = mathT2, 
         write_1 = write1, write_2 = write2, ses_1 = ses) %>%
  mutate(ses_2 = ses_1) %>%
  melt(id.vars = "id", variable.name = "var", value.name = "value") %>%
  separate(var, c("var", "time"), "_", extra = "merge") %>%
  spread(var, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `reshape`.

```
names(df1)[ncol(df1)] <- "ses1"
df1$ses2 <- df1$ses1 # according to your desired output
out <- reshape(df1, varying = 2:7, direction = "long", sep = "")
out[order(out$id), ]
#    id time mathT write ses
#1.1  1    1    10     2   3
#1.2  1    2    11     3   3
#2.1  2    1     9     3   4
#2.2  2    2     6     5   4
#3.1  3    1     7     1   5
#3.2  3    2     8     1   5
```

Not that we need to create a column `ses2` to get your desired output. If you want `NA`s instead where the values of `ses2` appear - which I think is correct, given you input data - take a look at the `data.table` solution below.

---

Using `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
melt(df1,
     id.vars = "id", 
     measure.vars = patterns("^mathT", "^write", "^ses"), 
     variable.name = "Time", 
     value.name = c("mathT", "write", "ses"))
#   id Time mathT write ses
#1:  1    1    10     2   3
#2:  2    1     9     3   4
#3:  3    1     7     1   5
#4:  1    2    11     3  NA
#5:  2    2     6     5  NA
#6:  3    2     8     1  NA
```

**data** Thanks to @Pete!

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  mathT1 = c(10, 9, 7),
  mathT2 = c(11, 6, 8),
  write1 = c(2, 3, 1),
  write2 = c(3, 5, 1),
  ses = c(3, 4, 5)
)
```